# Optimal check if IP is in subnet

Tags: node.js, algorithm

I want to check if an IP address belongs to a subnet. The pain comes when I must check against 300.000 CIDR blocks having subnets ranging from /3 to /31, several million times / second.

Take https://github.com/indutny/node-ip for example:

I could `ip.cidrSubnet('ip/subnet')` for each all of the 300.000 blocks and check if the IP I'm looking for is inside the first-last address range, but this is very costly.

How can I optimally check if an IP address belongs to one of these blocks, without looping everytime through all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Store the information in a binary tree that is optimized for range checks.

One naive way to do it is to turn each CIDR block into a pair of events, one when you enter the block, one when you exit the block.  Then sort the list of events by IP address.  Run through it and create a sorted array of IP addresses and how many blocks you are in.  For 300,000 CIDR blocks there will be 600,000 events, and your search will be 19-20 lookups.

Now you can do a binary search of that file to find the last transition before your current IP address, and return true/false depending on whether that was in one or more blocks versus in none.

The lookup will be faster if instead of searching a file, you are searching a dedicated index of some sort.  (The number of lookups in the search is the same or slightly higher, but you make better use of CPU caches.)  I personally have used BerkeleyDB's BTree data structure for this kind of thing in other languages, and have been very happy.